# How to propagate changes made to one doc, on to other related documents in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, observers

I have a meteor app where which has an observer to help detect any changes to one particular document. How do I propagate changes done to that doc, to other related documents without having to write multiple generic queries?

**What I have:**

orgPolicy:

```
{
    "_id" : "uudY4ekaZ4tPpN7KN",
    "organizationName" : "combat wombat systems 2",
    "priorityIP" : "2.2.2.2,6.6.6.6/24",
    "blacklistedServers" : "3.3.3.3",
    "policyType" : "orgLevelPolicy",

}
```

DeptLevelPolicy:

```
{
    "_id" : "Fb75pKgvePxakKTi4",
    "organizationName" : "combat wombat systems 2",
    "departmentName" : "mighty moose",
     "useOrgPolicyValuesForPriorityIp" : true,
    "priorityIP" : "2.2.2.2,6.6.6.6/24",
    "useOrgPolicyValuesBlacklistedServers" : true,
    "blacklistedServers" : "3.3.3.3",
    "policyType" : "departmentLevelPolicy",
}
```

**What I need to do**

If the `orgLevelPolicy` document changes, then only update those `deptLevelPolicy` docs which have the field's respective boolean flag set to `true`

**Eg.**

If `orgLevelPolicy.priorityIP` changes, then only update the field of `deptLevelPolicy.priorityIP` of those `deptLevelPolicy`, whose `useOrgPolicyValuesBlacklistedServers` is set to `true`

I have a crude observer such as below, but any change to the orgPolicy will triger a multitude of changes to **all** deptLevelPolicy irrespective of the fact that their bool flag is set, or if the field has even changed at all.

**(I hope my explanation is making any sense. Please let me know if I need to make any changes to better illustrate the scenario)**

```
 Meteor.startup(() => {

     var cursor = policies.find({
         policyType: "orgLevelPolicy"
     });

     var handle = cursor.observe({
         changed: function(orgLevelPolicyChanged) {
             console.log("Updating: departmentLevelPolicy: priorityIP");
             policies.update({policyType:"departmentLevelPolicy","useOrgPolicyValuesForPriorityIp": true},{$set:{priorityIP: orgLevelPolicyChanged.priorityIP, organizationName: orgLevelPolicyChanged.organizationName}},{multi:true});
             console.log("Updating: departmentLevelPolicy: blacklistedServers");
         },

     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be pretty close but you're trying to match the parent organization in your modifier instead of your query.

Do the name matching in the first argument to `.update()` (the *query*) instead of the second (the *modifier*)

```
const handle = cursor.observe({
  changed(orgLevelPolicyChanged) {  
    policies.update(
      {
        policyType: "departmentLevelPolicy",
        useOrgPolicyValuesForPriorityIp: true,
        organizationName: orgLevelPolicyChanged.organizationName
      },
      { $set:
        {
          priorityIP: orgLevelPolicyChanged.priorityIP,
        }
      },
      { multi:true }
    );
  },
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Michel. Let me try this out. Oh and yes, I missed the ```policyType```  while I was removing non essential code. I've added it back. As for the ```parentPolicyId```, my department name is going to be unique across all documents. So I'm guessing that will hold.